# Is bond dissociation enthalpy same for homolytic and heterolytic cleavage?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

In David R Klein's Organic Chemistry Book, Chapter of Radicals, one of the 'skillbuilder' questions is to identify the weakest C-H bond in the following molecule:

> [image]

The solution was to split each carbon-hydrogen bond homolytically one at a time and find which radical generated was most stable.

However, the question asked 'weakest C-H bond' without mentioning what kind of bond splitting is happening, so does this mean bond dissociation enthalpy for homolytic and heterolytic split of bond is same?

Comment: Well, if it was chapter about radicals, then it should be clear that it's about homolytic - hardly any ambiguity.

Comment: I don't think one can assume so unless it's explicitly stated.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/133669/heterolytic-vs-homolytic-cleavage-of-the-c%e2%88%92h-bond-in-cyclopentadiene

Comment: Well, if context wasn't enough then you should have check definition.

Comment: That question contains discussion of the post but really is not asking about the same question I have here.

Comment: Dissociation of a bond in thermochemistry & thermodynamics includes the products. Physically there is never a doubt. While speaking perhaps there might be a doubt, in cases. But as said in other comments, it shouldn't be the current case.

Comment: The question is for the weakest CH bond. Heterolytic bond cleavage is in almost all cases a more energy demanding process than homolytic cleavage; whether or not it is stated, it is irrelevant.